# How to control colors assigned to data groups?

Tags: r, dplyr, ggvis

Code:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl,am) %>% ggvis(~mpg, fill = ~factor(cyl)) %>% layer_densities()
```

The code above plots density graphs for each group of "cyl" and assigns different colors according to three levels of `cyl`: (4,6,8). But I don't have control over what color is assigned to each group.

How can I assign specific colors e.g. "red", "green", and "yellow" to each group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following to your `ggvis` function

```
... %>% scale_ordinal("fill", range = c("red", "green", "yellow"))
```